squid doesn't accept acl rule with NOT containing substring regex
I am using following rule to filter request header in squid.conf, the purpose is to match header value which does not contain string "abc"
acl noabc req_header X-My-Header ^((?!abc).)*$

But it gives error
FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.conf line 1594: ...


See https://serverfault.com/questions/1095083/squid-regex-syntax-description. There is no lookaround support.

Thanks to Wiktor, lookaround is not supported
